# Probability tree with multiple sources that highlights a specific path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest, trees

I am trying to recreate a graphic using latex. I want to create a tree-like shape that also includes the events with 0 probability.  It should look similar to [image: Target Image]

I tried to create this using the tikz and forest packages. However, I did not manage to include the grey events with probability 0 in the graphic. Is there another package or method that can easily generate such an outcome? Or do I have to "brute-force" this and manually define each node and edge using coordinates?

Thanks a lot already.

Comment: Welcome. // Please add the code of your best trial to your question. Thank you

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Using a matrix would also be straight forward alternative: https://tikz.dev/tutorial-chains#sec-5.3 and https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices ...

Comment: If you already tried something, show us. Otherwise we can't help you. I'd probably approach this from a [tag:tikz-cd] angle (matrix + lines connecting the nodes). The most interesting thing would be to do this more automatic. Though the placement of the nodes along the paths is a hard task to automate. Otherwise it's just a question of input syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `nicematrix` and `tikz`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\tikzset{outer sep=1mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1cm}
\begin{NiceArray}{lll}
    \color{gray}p(A)=0 & p(A)=\frac{1}{3} & p(A)=\frac{1}{6}\\
    \color{gray}p(B)=0 & p(B)=\frac{1}{3} & p(A)=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{4}{9}\\
    p(C)=1 & \color{gray}p(C)=0 & p(A)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{5}{18}\\
    \color{gray}p(D)=0 & \color{gray}p(D)=0 & p(A)=\frac{1}{9}\\
    \color{gray}p(E)=0 & p(E)=\frac{1}{3} & \color{gray}p(A)=0
  \CodeAfter
    \tikz
    \draw[thick] (3-1.east)--node[above]{$\frac{1}{3}$}(1-2.west)
        (1-2.east)--node[pos=.7, right=2pt]{$\frac{1}{3}\cdot1$}(2-3.west)
        (3-1.east)--node[below]{$\frac{1}{3}$}(2-2.west) 
        (2-2.east)--node[pos=.7, right]{$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$}(1-3.west) 
        (2-2.east)--node[pos=.7, right=2pt]{$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{22}$}(3-3.west)
        (3-1.east)--node[below]{$\frac{1}{3}$}(5-2.west) 
        (5-2.east)--node[very near end, right=-2pt]{$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$}(2-3.west) 
        (5-2.east)--node[near end, right=-2pt]{$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$}(3-3.west) 
        (5-2.east)--node[below right=-4pt]{$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$}(4-3.west)
        ;    
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```